Use the Zoom access_token without Revealing to the Client-Side
I need to integrate Zoom API into my website. I have created a Server-to-Server OAuth App. In the admin panel of my web application, I can fetch all the recordings with details. I want to show each recording on the client side as we use YouTube or Vimeo videos. I found some methods to do it in the client side.

Using <video> and <source> tags.
<video width="780" height="480" controls>
    <source src="https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/<?php $download_url ?>?access_token=<?php $access_token ?>" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video
</video>


Fetch the video through a PHP script file, and append it to the webpage.
<video width="780" height="480" controls>
    <source src="stream-recording.php?recording_id=4485" type="video/mp4">
</video>

The stream-recording.php will execute the cURL function to fetch the recording as an MP4 file. Then it returns that video file. And it will show the video in the webpage.


But, I also found some problems with those. In the first method, we have to reveal the access token to the client. Access token is very secure and I think it is not a good practice to use it frontend.  The second method slows down the web application. It is not good when considering the performance of the web application.
I want to know is there any way to hide the access token from client side without reducing the performance.
I tried to find out whether there were any other ways to do it without revealing the access token to the client side, but I didn't get any acceptable answer.

To be clear, the first option is a JWT, not a full-blown secret. When generating the JWT, you can set the exp so that if someone re-uses it elsewhere it will have a limited window. Although I haven't tested this, you can probably add additional things to the payload to at least add some "salt" to tokens, so maybe add the user ID. This will aid in debugging, too. And because the JWT generation is all on you, can you do this for each page-refresh, too, so everyone gets a unique JWT every time.

Docs for programmatically generating the JWT here: https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/api-request/#generate-video-sdk-api-jwt

@ChrisHaas I think you meant the Zoom JWT tokens. But, I am using the Server-to-Server OAuth App. I cannot include anything from my side, because Zoom API generates the Access Token.

I’ve never used this API before, so I’m going solely based on the documentation. From this page, it sounds like there’s a JWT that Zoom makes for you automatically in the web interface, but they then link to docs which show you how to generate these instead. From what I read, this is what you then provide? Or am I not correct?

Yes, you are correct, but I don't use Video SDK. I am using Zoom API and the Server-to-Server OAuth App. I mentioned them at first in the question description. You can read about it from this page.

Ah, okay, sorry, their documentation is a little confusing, I hate when companies divide things up this way. Are you able to use the play_url from the get meeting recordings endpoint?

Yeah, their documentation is too confusing. Anyway, the play_url is showing a full page with Zoom's logo and some other elements within the iframe. I want only the video to be viewed.
